# Application.kt: Unresolved reference: AndroidAlarmManager

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

I am trying to use the [android_alarm_manager_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager_plus) package to schedule background tasks in flutter. In their documentation, they have added the `Application` class code for JAVA, which is as follows -

```
public class Application extends FlutterApplication implements PluginRegistrantCallback {
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    AlarmService.setPluginRegistrant(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void registerWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(registry);
  }
}
```

But I'm working on a kotlin based project (without any knowledge of kotlin, I may add) and there is no documentation for this. I tried writing the kotlin counterpart to this code myself, but I'm still facing errors.
My `Application.kt` file -

```kotlin
package com.example.my_app;

import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;
import io.flutter.plugins.AndroidAlarmManager.AlarmService;

class Application : FlutterApplication(), PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        AlarmService.setPluginRegistrant(this);
    }

    override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry?) {
    registry?.registrarFor("GeneratedPluginRegistrant");
    }
}
```

The errors -

```sh
Application.kt: (7, 27): Unresolved reference: AndroidAlarmManager
Application.kt: (15, 9): Unresolved reference: AlarmService
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to add this Java/Kotlin code. That's for the old Android embedding. Note the "DEPRECATED" here in the title: https://github.com/fluttercommunity/plus_plugins/tree/main/packages/android_alarm_manager_plus#flutter-android-embedding-v1-deprecated